# 2D interpolation results in OverflowError: Too many data points to interpolate

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, 2d, interpolation

I am mapping a signal sampled on a spherical coordinates grid to a cylindrical coordinates grid. Obviously both are NOT uniform grid. Both grids have size 256 X 864 (row X col).

So I tried something like this:

```
f = interp2d(x, y, z, kind='cubic')
zz= f(xx, yy)
```

Here,

```
x, y = meshgrid(spherical_x, spherical_y)
xx, yy = meshgrid(cylindrical_x, cylindrical_y)
```

with `spherical_x, spherical_y, cylindrical_x, and cylindrical_y` all being non-uniform on 1D direction.

When I run interp2D, a error message came on, which says:

```
  File "C:\Users\MyComputer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\_fitpack_impl.py", line 48, in _intc_overflow
    raise OverflowError(msg)

OverflowError: Too many data points to interpolate
```

So, I am wondering what I am going to do with this non-unform 2D interpolation with Python/NumPy/SciPy? I know there is a `rectbivariatespline`, but it seems your original data have to be on a uniform grid. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try using basemap to do the re-projection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the object created with `interp2d` incorrectly. Its [call method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d.__call__) has arguments

> x : 1D array, x-coordinates of the mesh on which to interpolate.
>   y : 1D array, y-coordinates of the mesh on which to interpolate.

So, you should be passing in 1D arrays like `cylindrical_x, cylindrical_y` instead of meshgrid created from them.

Even at creation, meshgrid is not needed for interp2d: see the [example in documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d), which uses 1D arrays for x and y.

> there is a rectbivariatespline, but it seems your original data have to be on a uniform grid.

It has to be on a grid, not a *uniform* grid. For example, the 6 points with x-coordinates 1, 3, 10 and y-coordinates -3, 2 qualify as a grid. A grid is anything that can be specified by separate 1D arrays like I did above, instead of an array of tuples.

---

For interpolation on a sphere there is [RectSphereBivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectSphereBivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.RectSphereBivariateSpline).
But I do not  understand how you expect the conversion from spherical to cylindrical to happen by means of 2D interpolation, so cannot advise on an appropriate method for that.

Comment: But the error is thrown during the call to interp2d, not the call to f. This doesn't explain why `interp2d(x, y, z, kind='cubic')` should fail, since the documentation says that 2d arrays are fine for that one.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. It turns out I _really_ had too many points. It worked when I reduced the length of the arrays to around 10000 elements max.

Comment: interp2d works fine with 2d arrays. 

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html